# Android How to get Google Play Store Link before release

Tags: android, release, rate

I would like to release my app in a few days. In my app there is a rate-button where the user should be linked to the google play store. Is there an opportunity to add this function before releasing the app? Or do I have to release it and add an update?

Answer (score 26):

```
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>
```

Replace `<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>` by your package name